# React data content is disappearing on callback

Tags: reactjs, state, history

there is something strange happening with my code. My variable data (useState) is randomly empty when I call my callback when onpopstate event is fired.
I have 2 components and 1 hook used like that:

```
const Parent = props => {
    const {downloadData} = useData();
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState();

    const loadData = async () => setData(await downloadData());
    useEffect(() => {
      loadData();
    }, []);


    return <FilterPage data={data} onDataChange={data => setFilteredData(data)} />
}
const FilterPage = ({data, onDataChange} => {
    const {saveHistoryData} = useHistoryState('filter', null, () => {
         updateFilters();
    });
    const filter = (filterData, saveHistory = true) => {
       let r = data; // data is randomly empty here
       ...
       if(saveHistory)saveHistoryData(filterData);
       onDataChange(r);
    }
});


// my hook
const useHistoryState = (name, _data, callback) => {
  const getHistoryData = () => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    try{
      return JSON.parse(params.get(name));
    }catch(err){
      return null;
    }
  }
  const saveHistoryData = (data) => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    params.set(name, JSON.stringify(data || _data));
    window.history.pushState(null, '', window.location.pathname + '?' + params.toString());
  }
  const removeHistoryData = () => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    params.delete(name);
    window.history.pushState(null, '', window.location.pathname + '?' + params.toString());
  }


  const watchCallback = () => {
    callback(getHistoryData());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let d = getHistoryData();
    if(d)watchCallback();
    window.addEventListener('popstate', watchCallback);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('popstate', watchCallback);
  }, []);


  return {getHistoryData, saveHistoryData, removeHistoryData};
}
```

Any suggestions please

**Edit**
I'm sorry is not the entire code, just a draft. I download the data using async function. The data is loading fine but is empty only if we call the callback from the hook.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setData` to populate `data`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not calling `setData()` anywhere.

You are using `data` but not `setData` and you are using `setFilteredData` but not `filteredData`.

Furthermore it doesn't look like `updateFilters()` exist within `FilterPage`.

You are passing `onDataChange` to `<Filterpage>` but you are not using the property, only `({data})` which explains why it's empty. You might want to update the FilterPage signature:  `const FilterPage = ({data, onDataChange}) => {}` and use the `onDataChange`

Comment: The rest of the code is not important and is just too long

Comment: @patilanz I still think it's relevant to point out that he is not using the function needed to update the data.